# MacOS Swift Framework testing fail

Tags: frameworks, swift, xctest

I have a framework written in obj-c and swift.

Now i try to run a related unit test target, but I get this error:

```
2014-07-10 07:45:54.064 xctest[4908:303] The test bundle at /Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests.xctest could not be loaded because an unanticipated error occurred: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “SOGraphDB-Mac Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB.framework/Versions/A/SOGraphDB
  Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x10011c640 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB.framework/Versions/A/SOGraphDB
  Reason: image not found, NSBundlePath=/Users/steve/Temporary/Build/Products/Debug/SOGraphDB-Mac Tests.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “SOGraphDB-Mac Tests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}
```

Any idea what the root cause can be?
The error seems realated to "Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAppKit.dylib"

Both (framework and test bundle) compile without any error or warning (in Beta2)

Comment: try clean everything and rebuild

Comment: Please check if libswiftAppKit.dylib is included to test bundle membership

Comment: 1. clean and rebuild is my standard approch for any problem first.
2. no libswiftAppKit.dylib is not included in the test bundle, why should it?

Comment: btw. with beta4 i have the same problem.

Comment: It seems this problem is now fixed in Xcode6-BETA5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Ended up copying libswiftAppKit.dylib out of the Xcode application directory (I am using beta 3), into a directory that I could reference (not part of an application bundle), then adding the library to the "Link binary with libraries" setting for the test bundle.  My tests then started working.

FYI, the path for the dylib was at '/Applications/Xcode6-Beta3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx/libswiftAppKit.dylib'

Probably not a good final solution, but it works for the interim.

Comment: I accept this answer because it works now for me too (in may case now beta4). As you said not the best solution but we still in beta

Comment: I have the same problem again for Beta 6 now.

Comment: I opend a bugreport for it now (18113337)

Comment: The last bugreport was closed, i reopen another for Xcode 6.1 (19069079)

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem, though mine was an iOS test target, linking to a Swift framework,  that failed to run on Xcode 6 GM.  The test target had run successfully on an early beta of Xcode 6, but the final version reported the runtime error: `Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib`

I noticed that a newer project did not have the failure, so I compared the build settings and test code.  I was able to resolve the problem with three steps:

1. The test target needs the "Embedded Target Contains Swift Code" setting to be YES.  This tells the linker to add the Swift runtime libraries to the executable.
2. The test target needs an explicit value for the "Runpath Search Paths" build setting.  This tells the loader where to find the Swift runtime libaries.  I copied the following setting from a fresh new test target:

   ```
   LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/../Frameworks @loader_path/../Frameworks
   ```
3. The test cases need to explicitly import any modules that are used by the linked framework.  In my project, the framework used UIKit but the test cases only used my framework.  When I added an explicit `import UIKit` to the test cases, the link problem went away.

Comment: Including 
`LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks @loader_path/Frameworks` worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i have this problem again on Xcode 6.1. The three steps did not help in my case. I(re) opend my bugreport in the hope apple will add some checks to xcode target setup.

Comment: Ok i had to try this again and created a new test target. But the same issue it does not work. If a add manually libswiftAppKit.dylib it runs.

Comment: This was really helpful! In particular the third step was what solved the problem for me.

Comment: Step 2 fixed it for me. Step 1 doesn't appear to be necessary.

Comment: Step 2 is the thing that happens if you duplicate an iOS target and think you've changed all relevant settings to macOS: you need to add the extra `../` in this setting!

Comment: Step 3 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Since I keep running into this issue whenever I mess with build settings, here's the cleanest answer I can provide as of Xcode 8b5:

If unit tests don't run on **iOS**, make sure you have:

> **Runpath Search Paths**: `@loader_path/Frameworks`

If unit tests don't run on **macOS**, make sure you have:

> **Runpath Search Paths**: `@loader_path/../Frameworks`

This will show up as `LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS` in your pbxproj file. You can also add `$(inherited)` to make sure project-wide paths are added as well, but those are probably empty.

Lastly, I didn't need the `executable_path/...` settings, doesn't make a difference for me whether they're there or not for unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to add a single file to my test target, `AppKitTests.swift` (or `AppKitSpec.swift` in my case), and all the file contains is:

```
// While I don't know why, The.framework is built linked to libswiftAppKit.
// Frameworks do not embed the Swift libraries themselves, it's up to the host
// app to include the necessary libraries. So here we are, including AppKit on
// behalf of The.framework so that the tests can run.
import AppKit
```

Oh, I also added AppKit to the test target's set of frameworks.

Comment: I found the same thing, by adding `import Cocoa` for an OS X test.

Comment: I had an app, and as an experiment I decided to use a swift file inside a framework which is linked into the app. It had the problem linking to AppKit, so I did what you suggested, adding an empty swift file to the top-level application with `import AppKit`, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this occur to me in Beta 4 and it turned out that I had done it to myself without realizing it.

I had a Framework project called Fnord.  My FnordTests target contained a couple of unit test classes that had `import Fnord` at the top of each file.  For some reason Xcode was complaining about those imports and so I commented them out.  This is when I started getting the same symptoms while trying to run my unit tests.

I noticed that the settings for my FnordTests target were such that the target would be linked with `Fnord.framework`, and I realized that it might not be able to do that with the aforementioned `import Fnord` statements diked-out.

So I put them back in, and everything went back to normal.  Curiously, Xcode no longer showed those import statements as being problematic, but this is beta so I can forgive that.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: thx for your answer, but this is not the problem in my case. I have the (more or less) the same code in iOS and MacOS. On iOS it works on MacOS i get this error. Therefore xcode crash on iOS if i start to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, adding

```
import AppKit
```

in the Swift file fixed it